# Hadoop on Ubuntu - two different install directories?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I recently installed Hadoop 1.0.3 from the .deb provided by Apache. The package installed correctly, but there seem to be two directories that have Hadoop-related files: /usr/share/hadoop has jars and the site configuration files, while /etc/hadoop has hadoop-env.sh and some other XMLs; all of the Hadoop literature I've read thus far seems to assume there is only a single Hadoop install directory; could someone please elaborate on these two directories and their respective purposes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/share` is a platform-independent shared data directory (and hadoop is in java...) and `/etc/hadoop` is mostly host specific system and application configuration files.

Then, to configure hadoop, just use the following command and answer yes, yes, yes... !

```
sudo ./usr/sbin/hadoop-setup-single-node.sh
```

Then

```
sudo ./usr/sbin/hadoop-validate-setup.sh --user=hdfs
```

[Complete tutorial for single node](http://jinutechworld.blogspot.fr/2012/01/hadoop-100-single-node-configuration-on.html)

Comment: Hi Yohann,

Thanks for your answer. Would it be accurate to say that /etc/hadoop is $HADOOP_HOME, and if so, why does it not include core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, and hdfs-site.xml? Should I create a conf directory and copy /usr/share/hadoop/templates/conf/*-site.xml to /etc/hadoop/conf/ ?

Comment: See the edit in my post.

Comment: very helpful for me as well!